word choice: [enroll in or register for]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) I will enroll in the next job search workshop next week.
(1b) I will register for the next job search workshop next week.
(2a) I will enroll in a job placement soon.
(2b) I will register for a job placement soon.
Which word choice is correct? Thank you for your help.

In AME I would choose "register" for all of those. The only time I might choose "enroll" is when the item is a course of some description, and even there I might choose "register" depending on the time and the phase of the moon.*

Spelling note: Enroll is predominantly used in  American (US) English ( en-US ) while enrol is predominantly used in  British English (used in UK/AU/NZ) ( en-GB ).
